# question on coding take profit point of mt4

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql, mt4

I have question on take profit point of mt4:

I would like to set take profit point to stop loss * 2, so the code should be:

```
takeprofit = NormalizeDouble((Ask + ((Ask - stoploss)*Point()*2) + StopLevel*Point()),Digits);
```

However, it won't works, so anyone know how to fix it? I am new to mq4 coder. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you need to differentiate between BUY and SELL orders.

You also look like you are getting confused with `stoploss` and `StopLevel`. I'm assuming that your `StopLevel` is the distance of your stoploss in points.

If that is the case, your code should look something like this (you don't need to reference StopLevel if you already have the distance in Points):

```
if(ordertype==OP_BUY) takeprofit = NormalizeDouble(Ask+StopLevel*2*Point,Digits);
else takeprofit = NormalizeDouble(Bid-StopLevel*2*Point,Digits);
```